# $\{x\in E|f(x)<r\}$ is measurable for each $r\in\mathbb{Q}$. Is $f$ necessarily measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Suppose the function $f$ is defined on a measurable set $E$ and has the property that $\{x\in E|f(x)<r\}$ is measurable for each $r\in\mathbb{Q}$. Is $f$ necessarily measurable?

My answer is **Yes**, and the proof is the following:

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then choose a monotonically decreasing sequence of rationals $(q_n)$ that converges to $a$. (This is possible since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z},\exists q_n\in\mathbb{Q}\  s.t. q_n\in B(a,\frac1n)$). Then observe that $\{x\in E|f(x)\leq a\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\{x\in E|f(x)<q_n\}$. Now the result follows.

Is this argument alright? If it is not could someone please tell me where I've gone wrong? Thanks.

Comment: This is great! You have even shown the stronger statement that Borel sigma field is generated by intervals with rational endpoints.

Comment: Your proof is correct

Comment: Your proof is correct~